# Animation relative to previous animation

Tags: animation

I am running into an issue when I try and combine two movement animations. Both animations start at the origin. I am trying to combine them such that the second movement animation plays where the first one ends using relative position. Is there a way doing this without modifying the animation?

Thanks in advance,
Ryan

Comment: This is what Nonlinear animation editor window does.

Comment: My issues is that movement animation jumps back to the original spot - I'm using the NLA, but I want the second animation to play relative to the first.

Comment: In NLA you can add some animations one on top of the other (maybe add a LocRotScale single keyframe to let the second animation start in the right place). Just in the blend mode of the active strip set "add" instead of "replace".